# character counting game for random name android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, textview

I am trying to learn Android. I want to build a simple letter counting app for counting random name, that is my code l have problem with onclickListerner. Thank you in advance [Counting Themed Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lELgQ.jpg)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    TextView nameView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameView);
    nameView.setText("saya");
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
                    TextView nameView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.nameView);
                    nameView.setText("van");
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

            }






        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well what is the problem?

Comment: please l need help with onclick listener, l have error.

Comment: I see so many errors in that code, can you send a stack trace to help you better?

Comment: @ Eury Pérez Beltré ,stack trace!! you mean CatLog?

Comment: @user6026666 yes, your logs.

Comment: @Eury Pérez Beltré l tried many times, please can you tell me how can l get it?

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré Pérez Beltré  l have cat log, but l can not put it in comment because it is too long

Comment: Just paste the red ones (errors)

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré  03-06 19:33:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(826): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cct.mad.cxxxxxtasky/cct.mad.cxxxxxtasky.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: cct.mad.cxxxxxtasky.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré 03-06 19:33:12.400: E/AndroidRuntime(826): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cct.mad.cxxxxxtasky.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.view.View$OnClickListener

Comment: If you follow my comment you won't have that problem. The problem is that your class doesnt extends OnClicklistener.

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré , thank you so much l really need help, because this is my assignment.  you mean  l shoud do (public class MainActivity extends Activity extends OnClicklistener {

Comment: That's one way to do it, but it's easier if you do it in my way, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35833415/5294761

Comment: now l donot have error but eclipse asked me to add this method(@Override public void onClick(View v) {) what l have to write in this method?

Comment: thank you, now lam trying and please stay with me

Comment: Can you edit the post and put all the code you have now?

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré I updated my code

Comment: Try with this: https://gist.github.com/euri16/739a05f5981c8e1c98c4

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré, can you give me an idea for writing code here(  public void onClick(View v) {

Comment: Question, where are you going to show the chars count?

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré yes when random name is appear in edit text the player should enter the number of character, l putted the picture of game just click (Counting Themed Game).thank you.

Comment: You haven't add the reference to your edit text, but once you have it, you can do it like this: https://gist.github.com/euri16/b79413f441abe55dc6dd

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré Thank you so much it worked,If l put another question in stack overflow,can you help me l have another question for adding ratting bar for list view, l wrote the code for the list view with two edit text, it work properly just l want to add ratting bar.

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré,of course dear,I accepted it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
b.setOnClickListener() ;
```

With this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your code here
            }
        });
```

And remove this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stu
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're extending the onclicklistener, you should call `b.setOnClickListener(this);`

Comment: l changed b.setOnClickListener(this); ,most of the errors have gone but l noticed an error (public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener ) ,in  MainActivity  an then l putted mouse pointer (add unimplemented method), l added it but the method was(@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
}) ,my question is that really should exist in my code?